# C: Free up every malloc or only the main one?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have a pointer ***resultSet that I pass as parameter to my SQL function which reads an unknown amount of data from the DB. The actual handling of the data happens outside the function.

When cleaning up this pointer construct, do I just free the main pointer once and free finds all the subsequent allocations or do I have to free up every malloc I created?

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {

                // allocating the rows pointer
                resultSet = malloc(sizeof(void)*(int)mysql_num_rows);
                (*rows)++;

                for (i=0 ; i < mysql_num_fields(result); i++)               
                {
                // allocating the fields pointer
                *(resultSet+i) = malloc(sizeof(void)*(int)mysql_num_fields);

                // allocating the character pointer
                **resultSet = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(row[i])+1);
                (*fields)++;

                snprintf(**resultSet, strlen(row[i])+1, "%s", row[i]);
                printf("%s\t",**resultSet);
                if (i==6)
                {
                printf("\t %s\n",**resultSet);
                }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, for every `malloc()` you have a `free()`.

Comment: Word-for-word what I would have written. +1!

Answer (score 1):

> `free()`  frees  the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

It does exactly what it says - frees the memory pointed to. It doesn't look at what's stored in that memory; it has no idea about any other allocated memory. It just frees what you tell it to. So, as others have said, if you want to free all the memory you allocated, you have to `free` everything you `malloc`ed.

(Perhaps you were thinking of the more sophisticated behavior of C++, where when you destroy an object, its members are also destroyed?)

Comment: But in C++ you also have to delete your heap-allocated objects (I know how you meant the answer, just wanted to make this clear to other readers).

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `free()` for every `malloc()` you stated to prevent a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to basically work in reverse and free each allocation.